# WebGl 2D animation overlapping shapes

Tags: javascript, animation, 2d, webgl

I want to make an animation in WebGl of a 2D shape. The shape is supposed to rotate around it's own axis. The center of the rotation is supposed to be where the user clicks on the canvas, I have the rotation and the interaction all set up. The problem is that I want all the other shapes that I've drawn before to be displayed as well and have the new shapes overlap the old ones. For some reason my program always 'get's rid' of the old shapes.

So when i update the transformation matrix and redraw the vertices, it just rotates the shape but it does not keep the old shape intact
Here's what i got so far:

```
function main() {

 canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
 gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
 if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if (n < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }


  u_xformMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_xformMatrix');
  if (!u_xformMatrix) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_xformMatrix');
    return;
  }

  STARTBT.addEventListener("click", controlAnimation, false);
  STOPBT.addEventListener("click", controlAnimation, false);
  window.addEventListener("keydown", setColour, true);
  u_Colour = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_Colour');
  gl.uniform4f(u_Colour, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 1);
  document.getElementById('range_disp').value = 30;

  gl.clearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 1);
  canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){ var x = ev.clientX; 
            var y = ev.clientY; 
            var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect() ;
            TRANSLATE_X = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)        /(canvas.width/2);
            TRANSLATE_Y = (canvas.height/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);};



  animationF();


}
var animationF = function(){
     ANGLE_CENTER = animateCenter(ANGLE_CENTER);
     if(ANGLE_CENTER < 0){
         ANGLE_CENTER = 0;
     }

     draw(xformMatrix, gl, u_xformMatrix);
     if(RUNNING){
       requestAnimationFrame(animationF, canvas);
     }
 }

  var g_lastC = Date.now();
function animateCenter(angle) {
  // Calculate the elapsed time
  var now = Date.now();
  var elapsed = now - g_lastC;
  // Update the current rotation angle (adjusted by the elapsed time)
  if((now - g_lastC)/1000 > SPEED){
   g_lastC = now;
   var newAngle = (angle * 1.0) + (ANGLE_STEP * 1.0);
    return newAngle %= 360;
 }
 return angle;
}

function radioClick(source){
    if(source=='f1') SCALE = 0.5;
    if(source=='f2') SCALE = 1.0;
    if(source=='f3') SCALE = 1.5;
    if(source=='f4') SCALE = 2.0;
}

function controlAnimation(){
   RUNNING = !RUNNING;
   STARTBT.disabled = RUNNING;
   STOPBT.disabled = !RUNNING;
   if(RUNNING){
      g_lastC = Date.now();
      requestAnimationFrame(animationF, canvas);
  }
}

function reset(){
  document.getElementById('slideMe').value = 30;
  document.getElementById('range_disp').value = 30;
  ANGLE_STEP = 30;
 ANGLE_CENTER = 0;
 SCALE = 1;
 TRANSLATE_X = 0;
 TRANSLATE_Y = 0;
  gl.uniform4f(u_Colour, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 1);
  SPEED = 6;
  controlAnimation();
 }

function draw(xformMatrix, gl, u_xformMatrix){

  xformMatrix.setRotate(ANGLE, 0, 0, 1);
  xformMatrix.translate(TRANSLATE_X, TRANSLATE_Y, 0);
  xformMatrix.scale(SCALE, SCALE, 1);

  //xformMatrix.translate(TRANSLATE_X, TRANSLATE_Y, 0);
  xformMatrix.rotate(ANGLE_CENTER, 0, 0, 1);
  xformMatrix.translate(0, 0, 0);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_xformMatrix, false, xformMatrix.elements);

  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  // Draw the shapes
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 8);
  gl.uniform4f(u_Colour, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 1, 6);
  gl.uniform4f(u_Colour, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 1.0);

}

function setTriAngle(){
    var slider = document.getElementById('slideMe');
    console.log('Slider: ' + slider.value);
    ANGLE_STEP = slider.value;
}

function initVertexBuffers(gl) {

  add();        
  var n = array.length/2;
  var vertices = new Float32Array(array); // The number of vertices

  // Create a buffer object
  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  var FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;

  // Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  // Write date into the buffer object
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 2 * FSIZE, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  return n;
}

function add(){
    array.push(0.0); array.push(0.0);
    array.push(0.0); array.push(-0.3);
    array.push(0.3); array.push(0.0);
    array.push(0.5); array.push(0.25);
    array.push(0.0); array.push(0.5);
    array.push(-0.5); array.push(0.25);
    array.push(-0.3); array.push(0.0);
    array.push(0.0); array.push(-0.3);
}
```

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "gets rid of?" Also, some code would be helpful. Maybe you aren't drawing the old shapes every frame.

Comment: Hey, just posted most of my code. How would I know the transformed vertices of the old shape though. Right now mine is just spinning. I'm not sure how to save the information of all the old shapes.

Comment: It looks like you only ever initialize the vertex data once and update the positions when you click. Yet you're only drawing at most one shape. You need to save new vertex data into a larger buffer or draw the same shape repeatedly with different transformations (more draw calls and possibly less efficient).

Comment: How can I save the transformed vertex information though. I tried adding the original vertices again and then redraw all shapes, earlier, but that just layers them right on top of each other.

Comment: "have the new shapes overlap the old ones" Isn't that what you want, unless you mean the shapes aren't moving. One option is to save all the matrices themselves (copies) and apply them to each shape individually. Lots of draw calls could be bad but... I assume that once a shape is created, it won't change position, only rotation. You could create an extra attribute that specifies the rotation start position and another for a matrix so you don't have to update all the old shapes after creation. (So that would be two extra attributes, a matrix and some offset for the rotation.)

Comment: Yeah, but in a circular way, when I did it I only saw one shape because the other ones were right underneath it and not visible at all.

Comment: In addition, you could move some of the calculations into the shader so you just use time and the offset to get the rotation.